# npx not finding my package once installed

Tags: node.js, npm

I am creating a package in npm for practice purposes. When I publish it succeeds, and when running `npm i <myPackage>`  it installs it in the **node_modules**.

I can run it as `./node_modules/<myPackage>/src/index.js` but why isnt `npx <myPackage>` working?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "description": "Get your random quote right there in the terminal.",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "publish",
    "learn",
    "quotes"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "5.0.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To run it as a binary, and use the exact same folder structure, just add:

```
{
...
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "bin": {"<CLINameHere>": "./src/index.js" },
...
}
```

You can put any name in the CLI, for example **tsc** is for the package typescript (i.e they do not need to be the same).
Then after installing globally or as a binary using npx it will run.